# Dynamically import images from a directory using webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack, ecmascript-6

So here's my current workflow for importing images and icons in webpack via ES6:

```
import cat from './images/cat1.jpg'
import cat2 from './images/cat2.svg'
import doggy from './images/doggy.png'
import turtle from './images/turtle.png'

<img src={doggy} />
```

This gets messy quick. Here's what I want:

```
import * from './images'

<img src={doggy} />
<img src={turtle} />
```

I feel like there must be some way to dynamically import all files from a specific directory as their name sans extension, and then use those files as needed.

Anyone seen this done, or have any thoughts on the best way to go about it?

---

**UPDATE:**

Using the selected answer, I was able to do this:

```
function importAll(r) {
  let images = {};
  r.keys().map((item, index) => { images[item.replace('./', '')] = r(item); });
  return images;
}

const images = importAll(require.context('./images', false, /\.(png|jpe?g|svg)$/));

<img src={images['doggy.png']} />
```

Comment: I just like to point out that `.map` kind of expects a return value. In your case, one would use a good ol' `forEach` instead.

Comment: @BramVanroy or just make it a one-liner and return `r.keys.().map(...)` directly...

Answer (score 172, accepted):

> I feel like there must be some way to dynamically import all files from a specific directory as their name sans extension, and then use those files as needed.

Not in ES6. The whole point of `import` and `export` is that dependencies can be determined *statically*, i.e. without executing code.

But since you are using webpack, have a look at [`require.context`](https://webpack.js.org/guides/dependency-management/#require-context) . You should be able to do the following:

```
function importAll(r) {
  return r.keys().map(r);
}

const images = importAll(require.context('./', false, /\.(png|jpe?g|svg)$/));
```

Comment: Interesting... So, I am currently using 'file-loader' in my webpack config to move all those files to a single location in my apps public dir. That isn't happening here. How do loaders work with require.context?

Comment: *"That isn't happening here"* You mean the files don't appear in the output folder? Do you still get the path to them with the above code though? I don't think there needs to be done anything special to support this...

Comment: Not sure why, buy my loader wasn't being run and I was getting the original path. The loader is working fine now and the correct path is being provided! Awesome. Thanks for the introducing into require.context :D!

Comment: What to use if I have create-react-app(cra)? in`cra` `importAll` returned nothing.

Comment: This works for me, but how would you write the same thing in TypeScript? What would be the correct types for it?

Comment: I was able to get this to work in a typescript environment by just marking the require.context() call as // @ts-ignore . It worked fine in my Create-react-app environment, and also with webpack.  However, I observe that this is not really runtime importing--rather, at runtime, it will allow you to pull in any files that matched the specification in your source directories.  It will not just pick up *any* matching file in the desired directory at runtime!

Comment: If anybody is wondering how to use the returned array, then every item in the return array would have an object with `default` as a key, which can be directly used as `<img src={item.default} />`

Comment: @MaximilianLindsey You can look at the return signature of `require.context()` which I found to be `__WebpackModuleApi.RequireContext`, so I took that and passed it as the arg type in `importAll(r: __WebpackModuleApi.RequireContext) { ... }` and TS stopped complaining.

Answer (score 15):

It's easy. You can use `require` (a static method, import is just for dynamic files) inside the `render`. Like the example below:

```
render() {
    const {
      someProp,
    } = this.props

    const graphImage = require('./graph-' + anyVariable + '.png')
    const tableImage = require('./table-' + anyVariable2 + '.png')

    return (
    <img src={graphImage}/>
    )
}
```

Comment: I think more needs to be done to make this work with webpack.

Comment: Can you paste your webpack config file here?

Comment: I would not recommend using global requires like this - see https://eslint.org/docs/rules/global-require

Answer (score 13):

A functional approach to solve this problem:

```
const importAll = require =>
  require.keys().reduce((acc, next) => {
    acc[next.replace("./", "")] = require(next);
    return acc;
  }, {});

const images = importAll(
  require.context("./image", false, /\.(png|jpe?g|svg)$/)
);
```

Answer (score 12):

I have directory of png country flags named like au.png, nl.png etc. So I have:

```
-svg-country-flags
 --png100px
   ---au.png
   ---au.png
 --index.js
 --CountryFlagByCode.js
```

**index.js**

```
const context = require.context('./png100px', true, /.png$/);

const obj = {};
context.keys().forEach((key) => {
  const countryCode = key.split('./').pop() // remove the first 2 characters
    .substring(0, key.length - 6); // remove the file extension
  obj[countryCode] = context(key);
});

export default obj;
```

I read a file like this:

**CountryFlagByCode.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import countryFlags from './index';

const CountryFlagByCode = (countryCode) => {
    return (
        <div>
          <img src={countryFlags[countryCode.toLowerCase()]} alt="country_flag" />
        </div>
      );
    };

export default CountryFlagByCode;
```

Comment: On Nextjs 13 to avoid the warning - "Only plain objects can be passed to Client Components from Server Components. Module objects are not supported.", you need to use `context(key).default` instead of `context(key)`.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a functional component I made in Reactjs to simply show all the images inside the `media` folder in my project (same level as component) using the webpack docs and some of the answers here.

```js
import React from 'react';

const cache = {};

function importAll(r) {
    r.keys().forEach((key) => (cache[key] = r(key)));
}
// Note from the docs -> Warning: The arguments passed to require.context must be literals!
importAll(require.context("./media", false, /\.(png|jpe?g|svg)$/));

const images = Object.entries(cache).map(module => module[1].default);


const MediaPage = () => {
    return (
        <>
            <p>Media Page..</p>

            {images.map(image => (
                <img style={{width: 100}} src={image} />
            ))}
        </>
    );
}

export default MediaPage;
```

[image: rendered images from media directory]

With the way that I loaded the images the filenames are lost when mapping from the `cache` object but if you need them you can just use the `cache` object directly instead as the keys are the filename.

```js
// example with styles just for clarity
return (
    <>
        <p>Media Page..</p>

        {Object.entries(cache).map(module => {
            const image = module[1].default;
            const name = module[0].replace("./","");
            return (
                <div style={{float: 'left', padding: 10, margin: 10, border: '2px solid white' }}>
                    <img style={{width: 100, margin: 'auto', display: 'block'}} src={image} />
                    <p>{name}</p>
                </div>
            )
        })}
    </>
);
```

[image: images with filenames]

Comment: `require is not defined` showing this error

Comment: for me also not working

Comment: `src={`//localhost:3000/images/${name}`}` worked for me

Answer (score 6):

**UPDATE**
It seems like I didnt quite understand the question. @Felix got it right so check his answer. The following code will work in a Nodejs environment only.

Add an `index.js` file in the `images` folder

```
const testFolder = './';
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path')

const allowedExts = [
  '.png' // add any extensions you need
]

const modules = {};

const files = fs.readdirSync(testFolder);

if (files && files.length) {
  files
    .filter(file => allowedExts.indexOf(path.extname(file)) > -1)
    .forEach(file => exports[path.basename(file, path.extname(file))] = require(`./${file}`));
}

module.exports = modules;
```

This will allow you to import everything from another file and Wepback will parse it and load the required files.