# Importing multiple files in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am using create-react-app for my react project. It has got webpack configured for importing images. I wish to import multiple images (say 10) from a images folder into a component. The easiest way of doing this would be to add multiple import statement such as -

```
import Img0 from '../images/0.png';
import Img1 from '../images/1.png';
import Img2 from '../images/2.png';
import Img3 from '../images/3.png';
import Img4 from '../images/4.png';
import Img5 from '../images/5.png';
import Img6 from '../images/6.png';
...
```

The above code would not be a good choice when we have multiple files to import. Is there a way to add the import statements in a loop? I tried adding for loop but I was unable to modify the variables Img0, Img1 etc. (using ES6 `` didn't work as it converted the variable to a string)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can't use a single import statement, because the whole point of `import` and `export` that dependencies can be determined *statically*, i.e. without executing code, but you can do this:

```
function importAll(r) {
    let images = {};
    r.keys().map(item => { images[item.replace('./', '')] = r(item); });
    return images;
}

const images = importAll(require.context('./images', false, '/\.png/'));

<img src={images['0.png']} />
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42118296/dynamically-import-images-from-a-directory-using-webpack).

Comment: is there any way we can put this code in a utility file and pass the path as a parameter to avoid having to write this function in every component .jsx file?
I tried  
`export default function importImages(imagesDirectory) {
  return importAll(
    require.context(imagesDirectory, false, /\.(png|jpe?g|svg)$/)
  );
}`  
but this throws `TypeError: __webpack_require__(...).context is not a function` error.

Comment: @SushmitSagar everything in `require.context()` has to be a literal, so you can't pass in variables like `imagesDirectory`

Comment: `'/\.png/'` should be `/\.png/` (regex rather than a string)

Comment: I'm using this statement but getting error "require is not defined" @VityaSchel



export const imagesAll = importAll(
  require.context("../assets/appleImgs", false, "/.jpg/")
);

Answer (score 58):

I think maybe a better idea is to use an ***index*** file for your images folder.

Supposing you have this structure:

[image: Initial folder structure, where all images are on subfolders inside assets/images]

And you need to import all of your images to your **HomePage** component.
You can easily create an `index.js` file on your *images* folder, exporting all the images using *require*, like this:

```
export const Background = require('./bg/background.jpg');
export const First = require('./photos/first.jpg');
export const Second = require('./photos/second.jpg');
export const LinkedIn = require('./social/linkedin.png');
```

Then on your component you can import all of them with a single import.

```
import {
  Background,
  First,
  Second,
  LinkedIn
} from '../../assets/images'
```

And this would be your final folder structure:
[image: Final folder structure where we have an index.js inside assets/images]

Hope it helps! ;)

**Updated on 25/04/2021:**

If you want to use ES6 named imports:

***images/index.js:***

```
import Background from './bg/background.jpg';
import First from './photos/first.jpg';
import Second from './photos/second.jpg';
import LinkedIn from './social/linkedin.png';

export {
  Background,
  First,
  Second,
  LinkedIn
};
```

To reduce name repetition

```
export { default as Background } from './bg/background.jpg';
export { default as First } from './photos/first.jpg';
export { default as Second } from './photos/second.jpg';
export { default as LinkedIn } from './social/linkedin.png';
```

Answer (score 8):

I'm not sure it's really a good way but i was also looking for how to import several images to Components.
however, I wanted to import images like a module

> image folder

- a.png
- b.png
- c.png
- index.js

> index.js

```
import a from "./a.png";
import b from "./b.png";
import c from "./c.png";
const images = {
    a,
    b,
    c
}
export default images;
```

> Component which images imported

```
import images from './images'; //Your images folder location
```

> Usage in the render()

```
render(){
    return(
         <img src={images.a} />
    )
}
```

Comment: Note: you should `import images from './index'` instead of `from './images'`, or rename the `index.js` to `images.js`

Answer (score 5):

You can import all images from a folder by this function

```
function importAll(r) {
  return r.keys().map(r);
}

const images = importAll(require.context('./', false, /\.(png|jpe?g|svg)$/));
```

that `images` is a object of Module. you can access a file path by `images[index].default`

Answer (score 1):

Just create img folder with all  images  in public folder  and then you can do

src="/img/logo_main.png"

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=taMJct5oeoI

Answer (score 1):

Create an images folder inside the public folder which can be seen outside the src folder.

To call the images in a component, do this:

src="images/imageName.format"

Do not use src='../public'. It will show an error.

React will find the folders you have mentioned automatically

Answer (score 0):

A some kind of mixed approach to the above answers, which is maybe more clear, at least for me is:

1. inside the folder (e.g. in /src/components/app/assets/png/icons)  with many many images we create a file: "index.js" with content like:

   ```
    export const file1 = require("./IconRed_100x100.png");
    export const file2 = require("./IconSilver_100x100.png");
    export const file3 = require("./IconWhite_100x100.png");
    export const file4 = require("./IconBrown1_100x100.png");
    export const file5 = require("./IconBrown2_100x100.png");
    export const file6 = require("./IconGray_100x100.png");
    export const file7 = require("./IconMetallic_100x100.png");
    export const file8 = require("./IconMetallic_100x100.png");
    export const file9 = require("./IconMetallic_100x100.png");
    export const file10 = require("./IconMetallic_100x100.png");
    ...
   ```

(we can create this file outside of our app via a python script
else it would make no sense to use this approach at all, as we can then implement multiple import-lines inside of the react-component where we need the images; sure we need to know WHAT and HOW many files we want to import)

2. inside the component where we need these images (here it´s called ImageGallery inside /src/components/app/imageGallery/):

   ```
    import * as ALL from "../assets/png/icons";

    const itemsToRender = [];
    for (let x in ALL) {
     console.log(x);
     itemsToRender.push(
       <div key={x} className="image-gallery-item">
        <img src={ALL[x]}></img>
       </div>
     );
    }

    function ImageGallery() {
    return (
      <>
       <div className="image-gallery">{itemsToRender}</div>
      </>
     );
    }

    export default ImageGallery;
   ```

Then we rendered all the images from "/src/components/app/assets/png/icons" inside our React-component called ImageGallery.

Comment: That's what OP wanted to avoid.

Comment: @SaachiTech Can you explain this a bit more ? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend this approach, importing images one by one and add inside array of object is not an ideal way to use images in Reactjs.

```
// images.js
const IMAGES = {
  apple: require('./apple.jpg').default,
  cherry: require('./cherry.jpg').default
}

export default IMAGES
```

```
// App.js
import IMAGES from "./images"

// USAGE OPTION 1 
const IMAGE = {...IMAGES}
<img src={IMAGE.apple} />


// USAGE OPTION 2
const { cherry } = IMAGES
<img src={cherry} />
```