# Display a local image in reactjs doesn't work

Tags: reactjs

The task is simple: display a local image in a reactjs app based on dynamic data.

This is what I tried (assume `path_to_image` is derived dynamically):

```
<img src={require(path_to_image} />
```

generates an error:

```
Error: Cannot find module '../../images/logos/somelogo.jpg'
```

Without the require:

```
<img src={path_to_image} />
```

generates a broken image.

These two methods seem to be what people are doing, but no luck here. How do I solve this?

Comment: Are you sure the path is correct?

Comment: Yes it is, I checked.

Answer (score 0):

```
import image from "./path/to/image.png"
```

If you plan using more images in a dynamic way maybe you should store their paths in a db and then query the db for the respective path. Actually that's how it's done with a CMS for example. Even if you store the files on the same hosting, you would still save their paths to a DB instead of hardcoding.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```js
import SomeLogo from '../../images/logos/somelogo.jpg';
```

You can then use it like this:

```html
<img src={SomeLogo} />
```

As for multiple images, you could store them in a JSON array, and then loop through them and add each image.

Comment: there are 100+ images that can be generated dynamically. Importing all of them seems insane, isn't it?

Comment: @Eddy It does. Maybe use a loop?

Comment: A loop of imports? I mean, there has to be a better way, I'm not the first to work with dynamic images in reactjs, am I?

Comment: @Eddy I just found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44607396/importing-multiple-files-in-react). Maybe it could help?

Answer (score 0):

This does it:

```
let imageSrc = require("../../images/logos/generic.jpeg");
let dynamiclyGeneratedSrc = ...;
if (dynamiclyGeneratedSrc !== undefined) {
    imageSrc = require(`../../images/logos/${dynamiclyGeneratedSrc}`);
}
```