# How can I export all imported images from a JS file in React using a single export?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am creating a solitaire game in React. I have a `Card` component that renders a card to the screen based on the state of its suit, number etc. At the top of `Card.js` is a series of imports for image sources like so:
`import cardFrontTexture from '../assets/card_front.png'`

I have many of these imports so I figured I would move them all to another JS file and call it `CardImages.js`. I changed `Card.js` to import `CardImages.js` instead.

But I am having trouble figuring out how to export all of the imported images inside of `CardImages.js`

Essentially, is there a way to export everything all imports in a file such that I don't have to import everything individually by name in `Card.js`? I want to avoid doing `import { image1, image2, image3... } from './CardImages';` if possible.

```
// Card,js
...
import * as cardImages from './CardImages';
...

export class Card extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <img
                    onClick={this.handleClick}
                    className=""
                    src={ cardImages.image1 } // This is what I figured would work
                />
                ...
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

```
// CardImages.js
import image1 from '../../assets/image_1.png';
import image2 from '../../assets/image_2.png';
import image3 from '../../assets/image_3.png';
...

export ? // Not sure what to put here
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Importing multiple files in react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44607396/importing-multiple-files-in-react)

Comment: Half of it. I understand now what to change in `CardImages.js`. But is it possible to import everything from `CardImages.js` like so: `import * as cardImages from './CardImages';`?

Comment: Turns out I can! Thanks for the help :)

Comment: btw, I don't believe that this is a good practice. Why don't you just import it on the `Card.js`.Because you still importing all of that images **one by one** on `CardImages.js` anyway

Comment: I've seen this done before by other web developers as a way to reduce clutter in their component files. I suppose it isn't as useful here, but if I wanted to reuse the card images on another component I could just include `CardImages` instead of copy-pasting a long list of includes. But you're right in this scenario - it doesn't serve much of a purpose since `Card` is the only component using `CardImages`. This was more of an exercise for me to better understand imports and exports.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Thank you Alif for pointing me in the right direction.

I changed `CardImages.js` to this:

```
export const image1 = require('../../assets/image_1.png');
export const image2 = require('../../assets/image_2.png');
export const image3 = require('../../assets/image_3.png');
...
```

And I left `Card.js` as shown in the original question. I was able to use `import * as cardImages from './CardImages.js';` and avoid importing each export via its name.