# How can I dynamically load an image from my assets folder based on props in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, image, require, react-props

I am building a simple web app displays a panel of information for each item in a database. Part of this information is a picture that I would like to display alongside it.

This code in the panel component used to work fine:

```
<td>
  <img src={require(`../../../assets/images/${props.image_name}.png`)} />
</td>
```

However, I recently updated my modules and the images are now broken. Is there a new recommended way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do that should be this:

**First**: make `index.js` inside image folder then import all image

```
import img1 from "./image_name.jpg";
export const image_name = img1;
```

or

```
export const image_name = require("./image_name.jpg")
```

**Second**: import them like this:

```
import * as images from "../assets/img";
```

**Last**: use them like module

```
 images.image_name
```

Or

```
<img src={images[props.image_name])} />
```

Comment: The problem here is that I have hundreds of images and I feel there should be a faster way that importing and exporting every single one and then using them like a module.

Comment: take look at this :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44607396/importing-multiple-files-in-react

Answer (score 0):

let filename = "flower.png";
retun
<img src={`/images/${filename}`} />

Comment: I'm afraid this method gives the same result.

Comment: What do you want to do exactly? Send your code snippet here. I will answer you.