# reading all files in the public folder next.js

Tags: javascript, next.js

I have a folder called `Songs` in the `Public` folder. During render time I would like to render them:

```js
const renderSongs = () => {
 [ array of song files ].map(song => {
  ...
 })
}
```

tho I dont think I can use `fs` in next.js, so how would i do this?

Comment: What type of files are they? How do you want to render them exactly?

Comment: Does this help answer your question [Importing multiple files in react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44607396/importing-multiple-files-in-react)?

Answer (score 0):

> Note: You can import modules in top-level scope for use in getServerSideProps. Imports used in getServerSideProps will not be bundled for the client-side.
>
> This means you can write server-side code directly in getServerSideProps. This includes reading from the filesystem or a database.

Source: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getstaticprops-static-generation

or

https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getserversideprops-server-side-rendering

So basically you can use fs, but only in the `getStaticProps` or `getServerSideProps`, which will be run at build time, or on the serverside.