# How to display the image and background image from the array in react

Tags: html, reactjs

I am learning react. I am trying to display an image and background image from an array but it's not working.

I am getting the below output.

For image

```
<img src="images/system_analysis.png" alt="">
```

For Background image

```
<div class="proWrapper" style="background-image: url("images/system_analysis.png");"</div>
```

I need to know where I have to use `require` for my images. I tried to use it in the array but it's not working.

```
 imgIcon:require+"images/system_analysis.png",
```

I tried below code as well but it's displaying an error

```
 <img src={require(props.imgIcon)} alt="" />
```

**Note: I have more than 100 images and each image I can't import them manually**

I am sharing my code here.

**Main.js**

```
import React from 'react';

const OurService = (props) => {
  return (
   <img src={props.imgIcon} alt="" />
      );
}

const OurProducts = (props) => {
  return (
  <div className="proWrapper" style={{backgroundImage: "url("+ props.bg_image + ")"}}></div> 
      );
}
export {OurService,OurProducts}
```

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import {OurService,OurProducts}  from './Main'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import './App.css';


const AService = () => {
  const serviceArray=[
    {
      imgIcon:"/images/system_analysis.png"
    },
    {
      imgIcon:"/images/system_analysis.png"
    },
    {
      imgIcon:"/images/system_analysis.png"
    },
    {
      imgIcon:"/images/system_analysis.png"
    }
  ]
  const serviceFor=serviceArray.map((storeServiceArray, i) => {
   return   <OurService key={i} imgIcon={serviceArray[i].imgIcon}  />
  })

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="equalPadding">
        <div className="section-title text-center"><h2>Our Services</h2><p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p></div>
          <div className="row">
          {serviceFor}
          </div>
    </div>
    </div>

      );
}

const AProducts = () => {
  const productsArray=[
    {
      bg_image:"images/system_analysis.png"
    },
    {
      bg_image:"images/system_analysis.png"
    },
    {
      bg_image:"images/system_analysis.png"
    }
  ]
  const productsFor=productsArray.map((storeProductsArray, i) => {
return   <OurProducts key={i} bg_image={productsArray[i].bg_image} />
  })

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="equalPadding">
        <div className="section-title text-center"><h2>Our Products</h2>
         <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p></div>
          <div className="row">
          {productsFor}
          </div>
    </div>
    </div>

      );
}

 export {AService, AProducts}
```

**Index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {AService, AProducts} from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(<AService />,document.getElementById('a-services'));
ReactDOM.render(<AProducts />,document.getElementById('a-products'));

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48560592/is-it-possible-to-import-a-group-of-images-as-an-array-create-react-app-projec

Comment: @ksav, Thanks for the link, I checked that but the issue is, I have more than 100 images and each image I can't import it.

Comment: Please update your question with the above information.

Comment: @ksav, Yes, I added in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For dynamic path, you have to use template strings.

So instead of doing this, `<img src={require(props.imgIcon)} alt="" />`.

**Do this**

```js
<img src={require(`${props.imgIcon}`)} alt="" />
```

**EDIT**

Also, make sure to provide the correct path. Try adding a dot `.` to your image path. Like this `/images/system_analysis.png`

Working copy of the code is here:

https://codesandbox.io/s/image-bg-image-wookp?file=/src/Main.js

Comment: I tried this but I am getting error Attempted import error: './App' does not contain a default export (imported as 'App').

Comment: please check if you are doing any `default import` in your code somewhere for the app component..

Comment: I am new in react. I am using only code which I added in the question. I am not using any default import I guess.

Comment: I took your code adn tried using template string .. it is working ... one change for you to make is to add a dot `.` to your image path ... instead of `/images/....` , do `./images/system_analysis.png` .. indicate ... i will update my answer with a working example .. leave a comment if any further issues

Comment: Give me some time to check your answer

Comment: I checked. I am still getting Attempted import error: './App' does not contain a default export (imported as 'App'). Check this image https://prnt.sc/ry7cnm

Comment: Is this correct code import {AService, AProducts} from './App'; i am getting issue in this

Comment: yes it is correct.. because you are doing named export in App.js  (i.e. `export { AService, AProducts };`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211526/discussion-between-gdh-and-user9437856).

Comment: Yes, your code is working for me. Thanks for the help. upvote from my side

Comment: Please update the background image answer in this... so that I can refer in future.

Comment: sure - yes, i have updated the code in the sandbox ... the same link in the answer has updated working code....

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42118921/5385381).

If using webpack, you can use [require.context](https://webpack.js.org/guides/dependency-management/#require-context) to import an entire folder (`./myImageFolder`) of image files to match a regex (`/\.(png|jpe?g|svg)$/`) and then render them all with JSX from your react component.

```
import React from 'react';

function Images() {
  const images = importAll(require.context('./myImageFolder', false, /\.(png|jpe?g|svg)$/))

  return (
    <>
      {images.map(image => <img src={image} alt="" /> )}
    </>
  );
}

export default Images;


function importAll(r) {
  return r.keys().map(r);
}
```