# How to render a number of image-elements with different src in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
imageArray = ["../images/a.png", "../images/b.png"];

function renderImages(number){
  const imageElements = [];
  for(let i = 0; i < number; i++){
      const imageSrc = imageArray[i];
      imageElements.push(<img src={ require(imageSrc) } alt=""/>);
  }
  return imageElements;
}
```

The code works fine, the problem is the image source, I can put a static image source and it will work (I tried that), but when the source is dynamic (data coming form an array which is coming form a json file) does not work. Is there any solution to this?

Thanks in advance!

**Edit:**

The error I get is: Error: Cannot find module ".".

This could be a webpack problem

**SOLUTION**

For people who have the same problem, I was able to solve this problem by following this link: [Dynamically import images from a directory using webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42118296/dynamically-import-images-from-a-directory-using-webpack)

Comment: No need to use `require()`. The browser will make the request

Comment: I does not work with webpack

Comment: If I don't use require it will not give me any error message, but The image will not be rendered.

Comment: Then relative path is probably wrong. Inspect image requests in browser dev tools network.

Comment: I have tired to console.log(imageArray[i]) and I got the image path correct. I am 100% sure the path is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a module to export all images as imagelist

```
var cache = []; 

function importAll (r) { 
r.keys().forEach((key,index) => cache[index] = r(key));
} 
importAll(// your json here);

export default cache;
```

In your main module

```
import * as images from // whatever you name the module

var imageList = images.default
// Use imageList[I]
```

This happens because react uses webpack for bundling and each image will be specific to the newly bundled server.

To import individual images the react way use :

```
import image from //path to the image
```

PS : if any typos sorry. I am using mobile to type this answer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will try this and see if it works

Comment: Why do I get this error: TypeError: r.keys is not a function? am I supposed to change something in your importAll function?

Comment: Are you using webpack ?

Comment: Yes webpack is used

Comment: How are you requiring the json file. You need to use require.context

Comment: I got it thanks for the help. Finally I was able to make it work, I followed this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42118296/dynamically-import-images-from-a-directory-using-webpack that is almost the same as your solution.

Answer (score 2):

Try this way

Json file  data.json

```
{ 
 imageArray : ["../images/a.png", "../images/b.png"]
}
```

Change code like this

```
const data = require('./data.json');
const imageArray = data.imageArray;


function renderImages(number){
  const imageElements = [];
  for(let i = 0; i < number; i++){
      const imageSrc = imageArray[i];
      imageElements.push(<img src={imageSrc} alt=""/>);
  }
  return imageElements;
}
```

Comment: I get the same result

Comment: console.log(data)  in line 3 please

Comment: console.log(imageArray[i])  gives "../images/a.png", but the image will not render unless I use require. Using require will give the error I mentioned.

Comment: okay. replace this way <img src={ require(imageSrc) } >.. tell me what happend

Comment: are you using webpack ?

Comment: After running npm start all images go to a different folder (static/media/a.f23f2f.png) and they are given an ID like "a.47df83.png"

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what your project environment is so I'll be answering as if you're using a standard [MERN stack](http://mern.io/) though even if they are incorrect the core points remain.

Firstly, you are trying to use absolute paths like `../images/a.png` and that is not recommended.

You should set up a `static` folder for your application and put your files in that. After that you can [setup serving static files](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) and then start using relative urls like `/images/abc.png` instead.

This makes it so that you dont have to use `require` to fetch them, but rather just use strings as relative urls and your server will take care of the rest.

Comment: I am using react with webpack. I have used something called "create react app" that I installed using npm. This is my first react project so I don't know much.

Comment: looking at the folder structure of create-react-app it looks like it doesnt use express but it does have a [public folder](https://github.com/wmonk/create-react-app-typescript/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#adding-images-fonts-and-files) that will do the work. It's a small section and fairly self explanatory.

Answer (score -1):

image source resolved before js code comes into action.
you have to statically write the image location.

```
function icon() {
    return require('../images/a.png');
}
in jsx -
<Image source={icon()} />
```