# Dynamically load images in create-react-app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have **create react app**.
In my demo application I manage products and each product has an associated image.

How do I import images of those products which I am going to show?

e.g. I **can't** do

```
import cat from './images/cat1.jpg'
import cat2 from './images/cat2.svg'
...
<img src={cat}/>
```

Because this means I must import ALL images even if I am not displaying them.

How to dynamically import the ones I need?

ps. I found [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42118296/dynamically-import-images-from-a-directory-using-webpack#) question but their function shows nothing on my side, maybe because I have create-react-app?