# How to test webpack require.context function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, nuxt.js

[image]

I have a vue carousel component and I want to generate a list of The .png files in the static folder. Following [Dynamically import images from a directory using webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42118296/dynamically-import-images-from-a-directory-using-webpack) and Following https://webpack.js.org/guides/dependency-management/#context-module-api my component looks like:

```
 <template>
  <v-carousel>
    <v-carousel-item v-for="(item,i) in items" :key="i" :src="item.src"></v-carousel-item>
  </v-carousel>
</template>


<script>
  // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727167/how-do-you-get-a-list-of-the-names-of-all-files-present-in-a-directory-in-node-j
  var cache = {};
  function importAll(r) {
    r.keys().forEach(key => cache[key] = r(key));
  }
  var getImagePaths = importAll(require.context('../static/', false, /\.png$/));
  // At build-time cache will be populated with all required modules. 
  export default {
    data: function() {
      return {
        items: getImagePaths
      };
    }
  };
  //     export default {
  //       data() {
  //         return {
  //           items: [{
  //               src: "/52lv.PNG"
  //             },
  //             {
  //               src: "https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/carousel/sky.jpg"
  //             },
  //             {
  //               src: "https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/carousel/bird.jpg"
  //             },
  //             {
  //               src: "https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/carousel/planet.jpg"
  //             }
  //           ]
  //         };
  //       }
  //     };
  //
</script>
```

The commented out sections work to load the carousel image so I need to generate an object that looks like items. I realize I'm not there yet but when I run the  dev server I see :

```
[Function: webpackContext] {                                                                                                                          
20:20:42
 keys: [Function: webpackContextKeys],
 resolve: [Function: webpackContextResolve],
 id: './static sync \\.png$'
}
```

What does this mean and how can I test if I have the right path with the webpack require.context() function?