# React Native ListView for All Images in Assets Folder

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a folder `assets/images` with 200 images.  I want to make a listView with all the images and the image's file name would be the Text on the list view.

I've tried to make

```
import Images from './assets/images'
```

but always give me error.

Im using **react-native version: 0.59.9**
and **React: 16.8.3**

I try to make import folder:

```
import Images
```

Answer (score 3):

you cannot do it like that..

Add an index.js file inside images folder

```
 const images = {
  button: require('./button.png'),
  logo: require('./logo.png'),
  placeholder: require('./placeholder.png')
}

export default images
```

then import images properly

```
import Images from '../images'

<Image source={Images.logo}
```

mode the code like imports as you wish to make it working.

Comment: Then i cannot read all the images in a folder to renderize them inside a FlatList?

Comment: Try this maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42118296/dynamically-import-images-from-a-directory-using-webpack