# Change css on click of a styled component (map function)

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm trying to create a button to change the css of a component (Card.js) on Click but I'm not able to do it since I have to use a map function for a Tab.

That's the code.

The component Card.js:

```
const Cardbox = styled.div`
...
`

const Cards = styled.div`
    width: 150px;
    height: 220px;
    background: url(${props => props.bg}) no-repeat top center;
`

const Name = styled.h3`
...
`

const Role = styled.p`
...
`

const Card = props => (
  <Link to={props.link}>
    <Cardbox>
      <Cards bg={require(`./../images/Cards/${props.title}_Card.jpg`)}/>
      <div>
        <Name>{props.title}</Name>
        <Role>{props.text}</Role>
      </div>
    </Cardbox>
  </Link>
)

export default Card
```

Tab.js component (I get data from a constant file):

```
    class Tabs extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                ...
            }
        }
        ...
        makeHeroCard = (hero, index) => (
            <Card
                title={hero.name}
                text={hero.type.join(', ')}
                image={
                    require(`./../images/Cards/${hero.name}_Card.jpg`)
                }
                link={hero.name}
                key={index}
            />
        )

        render() {
            ...
            return (
                <div>
                    <button>Click here and change css</button>
                    <AppBar>
                        <Tabs>
                            <Tab label="Item One"/>
                            <Tab label="Item Two"/>
                            <Tab label="Item Three"/>
                        </Tabs>
                    </AppBar>
                    {value === 0 && (
                        <TabContainer>
                            <div className="GroupScroll">
                                <div className="Group">
                                    {heroCards.map((hero, index) => this.makeHeroCard(hero, index))}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </TabContainer>
                    )}
                    {value === 1 && (
                        <TabContainer>
                            <div className="GroupScroll">
                                <div className="Group">
                                    {heroCards
                                        .filter(hero => hero.type.includes('TANK'))
                                        .map((hero, index) => this.makeHeroCard(hero, index))
                                    }
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </TabContainer>
                    )}
                </div>
            )
        }
    }

    export default Tabs
```

What I'd like to do on clicking the button is:
 1. change width,height and src of the img;
 2. hide h1 and p.

How can I do it using `{heroCards.map(...)}`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm wondering why cant the styles you need be embedded in a general stylesheet and all you do is add or remove classes on the element?

Comment: Because it's not the styled-components way of doing things. Styled-components abstracts the classnames and the stylesheet for us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The map doesn't change much, it's not clear which card you want to alter but it's as simple as giving a new prop to your cards.

```
    const Card = props => (
        <Link to={props.link}>
            <Cardbox>
                <Cards bg={require(`./../images/Cards/${props.title}_Card.jpg`)}/>
                {!props.hideNameAndRole && (
                <div>
                    <Name>{props.title}</Name>
                    <Role>{props.text}</Role>
                </div>
                )}
            </Cardbox>
        </Link>
     )
```

Also, try and avoid dynamically require during rendering:
(inspired from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42118296/dynamically-import-images-from-a-directory-using-webpack))

```
    function importAll(r) {
        const heroCards = {};
        r.keys().map((item, index) => { 

          const key = item.replace(
              /\.\/\.\.\/images\/Cards\/(.+)_Card\.jpg/,
              '$1'
          );

          heroCards[key] = r(item);
        });
        return heroCards;
    }

    const heroCards = importAll(
        require.context(
            './../images/Cards',
            false,
            /\.(png|jpe?g|svg)$/
         )
    );
```

Then add a state to your Tabs component and change it on click on the button:

```
    state = {
        hideNameAndRole: false,
    }
    handleHideClick = () => this.setState(() => ({ hideNameAndRole: true })
    makeHeroCard = (hero, index) => (
        <Card
            title={hero.name}
            text={hero.type.join(', ')}
            image={heroCards[hero.name]}
            link={hero.name}
            key={index}
            hideNameAndRole={this.state.hideNameAndRole}
        />
    )
    ...
    render() {
        ...
        <button onClick={this.handleHideClick}>Click here and change css</button>
        ...
    }
```

You question mentionned css so instead of conditionally render `Name` and `Role` you could add an interpolation to their css:

```
    const Name = styled.h3`
        ...
        ${props => (props.hidden? 'visibility: hidden;' : '')}

    `

    const Role = styled.p`
        ...
        ${props => (props.hidden? 'visibility: hidden;' : '')}
    `
```

And active the interpolation through the same prop:

```
    const Card = props => (
        <Link to={props.link}>
            <Cardbox>
                <Cards bg={require(`./../images/Cards/${props.title}_Card.jpg`)}/>
                <div>
                    <Name hidden={props.hideNameAndRole}>{props.title}</Name>
                    <Role hidden={props.hideNameAndRole}>{props.text}</Role>
                </div>
            </Cardbox>
        </Link>
    )
```

Comment: Hi, really thanks! I'm now able to work on Card's width and height, but I made a mistake: the component is  <Card bg={props.image}>. So, how can I change the Card's bg image={require(`./../images/Cards/${hero.name}_Card.jpg`)}) on click?

Comment: The same way... Can you explain precisely the change you want to do?

Comment: If you can, I suggest that you import all the assets first instead of dynamically require during rendering. I'm updating my answer for that

Comment: I was trying something like ${props => (props.reduce ? 'background: url(${props => props.bg2});' : '')}. is it the right way?

Comment: Well, yes if `reduce` is the prop meant to change the background to `bg2` prop... You definitely can write this anyway