# How do I import a folder of images in React where each indvidual image in the file can be stored in state?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, image, state

I'm new to React and am trying to work on a practice project that will help me get better at the library. Right now, I'm trying to take a folder of images that contain 10 images and import them into my `App.js` file. This is the file that is being rendered to my HTML document. What I want to do is import these files (preferably into some sort of array), and make each of those array indices a variable in an object that is stored in state. I'll include my code and try to explain even further.

Here is a segment of my `App.js`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import AlbumCard from './AlbumCard/AlbumCard';
import AlbumImages from AlbumImages;

class App extends React.Component {

  state = {
    albumArt: [
      {title: "Supermodel", image: "AlbumImages/1.jpg"},
      {title: "A Moment Apart", image: 'AlbumImages/2.jpg'},
      {title: "Beerbongs and Bentleys", image: 'AlbumImages/3.jpg'},
      {title: "Another Eternity", image: 'AlbumImages/4.jpg'},
      {title: "Astroworld", image: 'AlbumImages/5.jpg'},
      {title: "The Story of Us", image: 'AlbumImages/6.jpg'},
      {title: "Slow Motion", image: 'AlbumImages/7.jpg'},
      {title: "Free Spirit", image: 'AlbumImages/8.jpg'},
      {title: "Birds in the Traps Sing McKnight", image: 'AlbumImages/9.jpg'},
      {title: "At. Long. Last. A$ap", image: 'AlbumImages/10.jpg'}
    ],

      i: 0,
      x: 0,
      y: 0,
      z: 0
  }
```

I want to import the folder `AlbumImages`, which consists of 10 images, and place each respective image into the `state.albumArt.image` variables. Is there anyway someone could help me solve this problem? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically import images from a directory using webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42118296/dynamically-import-images-from-a-directory-using-webpack)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible import each of images separately like this `import image1 from ./AlbumImages /1.jpg; import image2 from ./AlbumImages/2.jpg` and then use image1 as value of **src** attribute like this `<img src={image1} />`. For examle, you can add a property src to each object of array.