# Using import/require in Vue.js data property with dynamic value

Tags: javascript, vue.js, require

I'm trying to add a random image (image-01.jpg, image-02.jpg, ... image-05.jpg) to an `import`/`require` request that I'm using with the `data` option in Vue.js, the code looks like this:

```
<script>
  const randomImage = `image-0${(Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 1)}.jpg`

  export default {
    data () {
      return {
        image: import('@/some/module/in/some/folder/\'' + randomImage + '\'')
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

But the error output I'm getting is:

`Error: Cannot find module './'image-03.jpg'' at eval (eval at ./some/module/in/some/folder lazy recursive ^\.\/'.*'$`

Is there a way to achieve this?

**Many thanks in advance.**

---

P.s. I've also tried the following:

```
<script>
  const randomImage = `@/some/module/in/some/folder/winter-0${(Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 1)}.jpg`

  export default {
    data () {
      return {
        image: import(`${randomImage}`)
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

But get a similar error.

---

P.p.s. I should also add that I've tried using `require` instead of `import`.

Comment: Are you going to use this image in your template?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamically import images from a directory using webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42118296/dynamically-import-images-from-a-directory-using-webpack)

Comment: @Nitheesh - yes, I will be using the `image` value in my `<template>...</template>` tag.

Comment: @Fraction - I'll have a look through the answers given in the link you've provided. If I find something that works I'll update here with the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To update on this (and I'm not sure this is the 'proper' way of doing it).. the code example below now works.

```
<template>
  <img
    alt="Random image"
    :src="image"
  />
</template>

<script>
  const randomImage = `image-0${(Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 1)}`

  export default {
    data () {
      return {
        image: null
      }
    },

    mounted () {
      import('@/some/module/folder/' + randomImage + '.jpg').then((image) => {
        if (image.default) {
          this.image = image.default
        }
      })
    }
  }
</script>
```

If anyone has a more elegant solution then please let me know.

Comment: I found the information in this link quite useful, in case anyone else runs into a similar problem: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/4292