# How can I display my image in a React app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactstrap

I am having trouble loading images in a React app created with create-react-app. Loading the images return a 304 Not Modified response.
Here is my code:
App.js:

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import { Navbar, NavbarBrand } from 'reactstrap'
import Menu from './components/MenuComponent';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Navbar dark color="primary">
        <div className="container">
          <NavbarBrand href="/" >Home</NavbarBrand>

        </div>

      </Navbar>

      <Menu />

      <img src="assets/images/uthappizza.png" alt=""/>

    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Thanks!

Comment: <img src={require("assets/images/uthappizza.png")} alt=""/> inside require just enter image path

Comment: @ShivanshuGupta does my assets folder have to be inside the src folder?

Comment: @Joseph Yes....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files/, you need to do:

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import { Navbar, NavbarBrand } from 'reactstrap'
import Menu from './components/MenuComponent';
import './App.css';
import pizza from './assets/images/uthappizza.png'; // Tell webpack this JS file uses this image

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Navbar dark color="primary">
        <div className="container">
          <NavbarBrand href="/" >Home</NavbarBrand>
        </div>
      </Navbar>
      <Menu />
      <img src={pizza} alt=""/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

You can also read more about how [WebPack works](https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-management/#loading-images) here.

Comment: Thanks. Do I have to import an image every time I need to use an image? Let's say I am receiving multiple image paths from an api/json file, how can I import all of them?

Comment: Yes you can. See this question and answers https://stackoverflow.com/a/42118921/1418750

Answer (score 0):

This is the right way of importing static assets:

```js
import VariableName from "../relative/path/to/image.png";
import image from './assets/images/uthappizza.png';
```

The imported variable `image` contains the full URL relative to the app for `assets/images/uthappizza.png` . You just need to change to:

```js
import image from './assets/images/uthappizza.png';

<img src={image} alt="Logo" />;
```