# I am getting a void returned when trying to dynamically import images from a directory using webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack

For context, I was reviewing [Dynamically import images from a directory using webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42118296/dynamically-import-images-from-a-directory-using-webpack)

When trying to use the `importAll(i)` function,

It seems that my images object does not get populated  and/or the images object is undefined.

Can anyone help as to where I am going wrong?

```
function importAll(i) {
    let images = {};
    i.keys().map((item, index) => {images[item.replace('./', '')] = i(item);
    return images;
});
    
}

const images = importAll(require.context('../images', false, /\.png$/));


<img src={ images['chatLogo.png'] } alt="Chat Logo" width="300" height="250" />
```

My file directory:

[image: Directory]

I've got it in the components folder as I was trying to figure out if it was my filepath that was the issue.

Comment: Your `importAll` function doesn't `return images`, your map function does. You need to move a `}` up so the return statement is in the outer function.

Comment: When the return statement is moved a } up, the images object remains empty, let images = {}

Comment: So maybe in addition to that problem `i.keys()` is empty?

Comment: It would seem so. This would've been great to implement as I'm new to React & Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Your `importAll` function doesn't `return images`, your *map* function does. You need to move a `}` up so the return statement is in the outer function.

Formatted for clarity, but otherwise unmodified:

```js
function importAll(i) {
    let images = {};
    i.keys().map((item, index) => {
        images[item.replace('./', '')] = i(item);
        return images; // <-- this should be outside the map function
    });
    // return images; <-- should be here
}
```