# ReactJS: Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to read images from folder in reactJS application. I tried with this [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42118296/dynamically-import-images-from-a-directory-using-webpack) that is very close to my question on SO but console showing me this error each time.

Here is my code

```
<img src={require('../images/Mobile/Grab & Go.png')} alt="" />
```

Console is showing this error

> Portfolio.jsx:23 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

Answer (score 1):

You have to import the image then use it as a value passed to the `src` prop of `img`.

```js
import Image from '../images/Mobile/Grab & Go.png';
...
<img src={Image} alt="" />
```