# Rendering Image with Correct File Path in React, but Image isn't Showing for Some Reason

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, jsx

I am currently trying to map svg's in an array of objects into a dropdown menu in React, however I am noticing that when I try to render an Image element in this format:

```
<img src='../images/ad.svg' />
```

The image isn't showing. Now this is weird because if I import the image and render it with JSX it DOES render (with the exact same file path).

```
import testImage from '../images/ad.svg';
<img src={testImage}/>
```

Has anyone encountered this problem before?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Jake

Comment: 2nd snippet is correct way of doing this in react. During build `testImage` will have path to that svg file and that svg file will be included in generated dist folder thus it works.

Comment: Ok, so if I wanted to map through the options for a drop-down, would I best import the whole folder using import * flagsvgs and do it that way? @bogdanoff

Comment: if you want to import all files in a directory, check webpack's `require.context` api also this [S.O answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42118296/dynamically-import-images-from-a-directory-using-webpack).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work just fine.

```
import a from "./svg/a.svg"
import b from "./svg/b.svg"
import c from "./svg/c.svg"

export default function Dropdown () {
    let images = [
       {name: "Image A", img: a},
       {name: "Image B", img: b},
       {name: "Image C", img: c},
    ]

    return (
        <DropdownMenu>
            {images.map(obj => <DropdownItem key={obj.name} img={obj.img}/>}
        </DropdownMenu>
    )
}
```

You can also create the *images* array in another file and import it instead of importing them in *Dropdown.js* to make it more organized. I would do that if the list has more than, lets say... 10 SVGs.