# Serving static images with Webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I am having trouble with webpack and react serving static images on webpack dev server.

This is my currenct folder structure

[image]

As you can see I have a assets folder witch holds all my images
This is my webpack entry and output configuration

[image]

Where client entry is source of my react project
CLIENT_ENTRY: path.join(process.cwd(), 'src/client/index.jsx')

Now here is my output in BASH when webpack has done its part
[image]

And here is where I am trying to load images from assets folder in root of the project

[image]

Only the import works witch is expected.

I have tried to change the output and public path like so in webpack 
path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
publicPath: '/',

path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/assets'),
publicPath: '/assets/',

path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
publicPath: '/assets',

path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
publicPath: '/assets/',

etc.. etc..

If someone could help me that would be great

Comment: I forgot to mention that in my src/server/server.js I am using express and serving static content like so
// Serve static content for the app from the assets directory and build directory
app.use(express.static('build'));
app.use(express.static('assets'));

Comment: Are they in a relative path to the outputted Main.js? Otherwise it clearly wouldn't work.
You can have them in your source and build with with Webpack, if you test for .jpg. I do something like: `{
                test: /\.(ttf|otf|eot|svg)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?|(jpg|gif)$/,
                loader: 'file-loader?name=./static/fonts/[name].[ext]'
            } `

Comment: Yes they are like so             <script defer src="${ assets ? assets.main.js : '/main.js' }" ></script>

Comment: So something like const file = {
  test: /\.(woff2?|jpe?g|png|gif|ico)$/,
  use: 'file-loader?name=./assets/images/[name].[ext]'
};

Comment: Something along those lines, yes. Give it a shot and update your javascript to include the relative path of the outputted images and let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To follow the idea behind webpack you need to process assets from your source to your target.

Therefore, add your images to a relative path in your source (*where your entry is, essentially*) and add a loader for the images (*and perhaps other things*) as such:

```js
{
    test: /\.(woff2?|jpe?g|png|gif|ico)$/, 
    use: 'file-loader?name=./assets/images/[name].[ext]'
}
```

Just update the relative path of the outputs to the assets/images and they should be able to load.

Comment: This only works if I import the image. So if I remove for example import test from './test.jpg' then the other image src wont work. Do you know what might be the problem?

Comment: All the other sources worked when the import of test.jpg was there? That sounds strange.

Comment: No not all only                 <img src="assets/images/test.jpg" />
                <img src="/assets/images/test.jpg" />

Comment: It appears test.jpg is the only image in assets/images?

Comment: Then it makes sense. You look to call it with `{test}` and it's the only valid component there(from what I can see). So if you remove the import, it doesn't render.

Comment: Yes it dosen't render

Comment: That makes sense, since you removed it. Check out this response: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32612912/dynamically-add-images-react-webpack

Comment: Yes but I want to be able to render from image path because I will get the image path through service. So it has to be like <img src="path/to/my/assets/images" />. This will be dynamic not hardcoded images

Comment: By path do you mean locally on the server side, or as a link to some other site?

Comment: Locally not other site

Comment: Then I don't see an issue with the answer I linked you to above. That should solve it :-) `import test from 'YOUR_PATH/test.jpg';` and call it by `<img src={test}/>`

Comment: Because I will get data from service like user: {name: 'John Smith', imageUrl: 'path/to/my/assets/folder'} and there can be many users it will never be the same image of caurse. So I cant do like import thisUser from 'specific-path.jpg'; Do you understand or is my explanation not good enough?

Comment: Basically I want to be able to reference images with strings not imports

Comment: I understand it now, but the scope is a bit broader than your initial question. Now you're in the territory of user session and state. You likely have to bind a user property to a specific image and pass it as a props. For this, I suggest making a new question.

Comment: No no I have implemented that all. But as I said. The images will be there and the user data logic is already implemented. But the problem is that I cant serve images through my assets folder. So I cant do like <img src="assets/images/test.jpg" /> That is my only dilemma

Comment: I figured it out. I am the idiot. So I have a devServer.js and a server.js and in the devServer I didn't tell express to server from assets folder I only did it in server.js. Thank for everything though :)

Answer (score 2):

In your webpack.config.js, you will need to serve the assets folder as well.

```
{
  ...webpack,
  devServer: {
    contentBase: [__dirname + '/public', __dirname + '/assets'],
    ...webpack.devServer,
  },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**This is a fix for React(18.1.0) and webpack (5.72.1)**

This works for both importing inside a <img src=""/> and <img src={url}/> without having to import or require().

You must first tell Webpack to include images in your dist bundle, I used a file loader for this.

```
npm install file-loader --save-dev
```

**Then you must set a rule inside your webpack.config.js**

```
{
  test: /\.(gif|png|jpe?g)$/,
  loader: 'file-loader',
  options: {
      name: '[path][name].[ext]'
  }
},
```

**The structure of my project is:**

```
project-name/
├── public
│   └── index.html
│   └── assets/
│       └── images/
│           └── *.png
├── src/
│   └── components
│       └── filewhereineedtoimport.js
│
├── webpack.config.js
└── package.json
```

**Importing in component**

```
<img src="/assets/images/desired-image.png"/>
```

**My start script inside package.json**

```
"scripts": {
"start": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --open 
 --hot",
"build": "webpack --mode production"
}
```