# Images don't show only when optional html parameter is provided (but do show otherwise)

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, reactjs

I have parent component that shows an image at a specified path *(note: the image is already saved in my project)*.  This path optionally can have additional parameters.  If the

For example, The **image is displayed** ([image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7LWZq.jpg)) if the html path is:

```
    www.mysite.com/myPath
```

The component **is** displayed but **image is broken** ([broken image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iwfVV.png)) if the html path is:

```
    www.mysite.com/myPath/someFilterForThisPage
```

**Router**

```
// Libraries
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';

// Components
import Home from './containers/Home';
import NotFound from './components/NotFound';
import MyComponent from './components/MyComponent';

// Redux
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import {createStore} from 'redux';
import allReducers from './reducers';

const store = createStore(
  allReducers,
  window.devToolsExtension && window.devToolsExtension()
);

// Routes
const routes = (
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
      <div>
        <Provider store={store}>
            <Switch>
              <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
              <Route path="/myPath/:filter?" component={MyComponent} />
              <Route component={NotFound} />
            </Switch>
        </Provider>
      </div>
    </Router>
);

export default routes;
```

I don't think the issue is with my router.js file since the component still shows when a `filter` is applied in the html path (the image is just broken, [image: broken]), but I am providing it just in case I am misunderstanding something.

**My Component:**

```
// React
import React from 'react';

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    <div>
        <img src={"img/x.png"} id="someId" alt=""/>  // ISSUE
        // ...
        // some divs that show/don't based on the filter of the html path
        // ...
    </div>
  }
}

export default MyComponent;
```

I have looked at and tried some of the following, but with little luck:

- [React won't load local images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34582405/react-wont-load-local-images)
- [Dynamically Add Images React Webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32612912/dynamically-add-images-react-webpack)

I think these are different because these are mainly issues related to being unable to display images at all.  I am able to display the image, but only when the optional html parameter is not set.

**Does anyone know why the image is showing, but only if there is no extra html parameter?**

Many thanks.

Comment: Are you able to strip out just the source you need? You can use regex to get just the image url without the extra params at the end.

Comment: Stripping out just that source would likely not be a suitable solution because this same issue is happening for all images in the `img` folder where that image is located, so this solution would mean stripping out every single image used throughout the project (which would be a significant number)

Comment: Ah okay, it sounded like you were working with dynamic image paths. So these are images that are already saved in your project?

Comment: @ChaseDeAnda yes, the images are already saved in my project (good point to clarify).  I have updated the question to contain that point as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any reason why `{"img/x.png"}` is not accessing root? Such as `{"/img/x.png"}` or setup your env domain as a global variable and add that in there otherwise you are looking inside every directory you hit for an img directory.

Comment: Beautiful!  I had tried `{"./img/x.png"}` (the way I do for `import` statements in React) but it didn't solve the issue... your solution on the other hand did!  Logical, simple solution.  Thank you!