# Image Loading Error React Create React App

Tags: image, reactjs, create-react-app

I want to upload images from files in my React application (I use create-react-app).It didn't show up and the error message appeared in the terminal.

I tried the proposed solution in the following questions but It didn't work out for my app.

[React won't load local images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34582405/react-wont-load-local-images)

[Dynamically Add Images React Webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32612912/dynamically-add-images-react-webpack)

The error message is

`Module not found: Can't resolve './Image.png' in '/Users/ayumi/my-app/src/components'`

Main.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Image from './Image.png';


export default class Parent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <img src={Image} alt=""} />
      </div>
    );
  }
 }
```

File structure

```
|-- src
|   ` app.js
|    ` image.jpg
|   `-- components
|      `Main.js
```

***Edited***
Thanks to Chris's comment, it figure it out that just one comma was missing in import area.

```
import React from 'react';
import Image from '../Image.png';
```

Comment: if `./` resolves to `/Users/ayumi/my-app/src/components` and your image is one level higher, just import it like`../Image.png`. So just add another `.`.

Comment: Oh my god. It's a silly mistake. It works fine now. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You need to go up a directory to import your png like so:

```
import Image from '../Image.png';
```