# Having trouble importing Image into React App

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to load in an image file that's contained within my `src` folder. I'm loading it into `App.js` like so:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import logo from 'images/logo.png';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <header>
            <img src={logo} alt={"logo"}/>
        </header>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Unfortunately, I get this error:

```
./src/App.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'logo.png' in '/src'
```

I arrived at this code with this Stack Overflow answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35454832/7386637
..but what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: try to use a relative link (`./images/logo.png` if your images folder is in the same folder than `App.js`)

Comment: That did it. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome !

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be using file paths like this, you need to add a [`resolve`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve-modules) property to your webpack config, like so

```
  resolve: {
    modules: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'PATH_THAT_HOLDS_YOUR_IMAGE_DIRECTORY')]
  },
```

So for example if your images live in `project/assets/images/` and your webpack config lives in `project/` then in the above you would replace `PATH_THAT_HOLDS_YOUR_IMAGE_DIRECTORY` with `assets`.

Using `import logo from 'images/logo.png';` would work then. (Reminder that you need to restart your dev-server in order for changes in webpack config to take effect)

Otherwise, relative paths will work fine, as mentioned.