# How to resolve 3rd party library assets paths in CRA application?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, create-react-app

I have a prebuilt es5 module (say `library`) that has the following structure:

```
node_modules
|
`- library
    |
    `- build
        |
        `- images
        |   - img1.svg
        |   - img2.svg
        |   - logo.svg
        |    ...
        ` - package.json
        ` - index.js
```

`library` module exports ui components including `Logo` that renders an img element:

```
<img src="/images/logo.svg">
```

When I'm using `Logo` in CRA app, an `/images/logo.svg` path is not resolved correctly and Logo displays an empty image.
Is there any way to copy `library` images and resolve paths during the build step? Wish to avoid copying images into `/public` folder manually as well as ejecting CRA.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `<img src="/imgages/logo.svg">` It seems you have mis-spelled the term `images`. Check this

Comment: That's a typo, thanks.

Comment: Check this, it might help: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32612912/dynamically-add-images-react-webpack)

Comment: `<img src={require("/images/logo.svg")} />` Try this way.