# Displaying alt content instead of image in React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, e-commerce

[image not displaying](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QIvD2.png)

```
function ProductScreen(props) {
const product = data.products.find((x) => x._id === props.match.params.id)
 
<div className="col-2">
                <img className="large" src={product.image} alt={product.name}/>
            </div>
```

I'm trying to render the image of specific id but only alt attribute is being displayed. Can anyone help me with it. Thankyou

Comment: Just console the product and check whether img key has value or not.
Suggestion: Best practice is to provide a fallback

Answer (score 1):

You might need to use require()...in order for react to process it.

```
<img className="large" src={require(product.image)} alt={product.name}/>
```

The other way of doing it is importing the image into a variable and referencing that in your {src}. A quick search yields many results -

Following is from https://stackoverflow.com/a/32613874/5867572

```
  const imgSrc= './image1.jpg';
  return <img src={imgSrc} />
```

Following is from https://stackoverflow.com/a/35454832/5867572

```
  import LogoImg from 'YOUR_PATH/logo.png';
  <img src={LogoImg}/>
```

Comment: saying Error: cannot find module './imagePath'

Comment: thankyou so much for your response but it didn't solve the issue

Comment: Sorry - one thought - are you sure that your relative path to the image is correct - - it needs to be pointing the img src to the right directory.

Comment: Yes it is correct because in homepage all the images are rendering properly but when i click on specific product image alt attribute is being rendered

Answer (score 0):

**Console log** the **product** and see if your **image URL** is okay, you'll get more idea why it's not displaying

```
const product = data.products.find((x) => x._id === props.match.params.id)
console.log(product);
```

[image]

Comment: sure here it is

Comment: okay can you do one more things? just inspect the image and see the full url of the image. and then copy the url and paste it in a new window. does it works? if not then may be "./" is the problem. image name "images/p1.jpeg" may solve the issue instead of  "./images/p1.jpeg"

Comment: can you please mark the answer as resolved! thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

Obviously this is skipping the problem but what about:

```
<div className="col-2">
  <img className="large" src={product.image} title={product.name}/>
</div>
```